# Возможно ли в css обратиться из дочернего элемента к элементу родителя?

Tags: html, css

К примеру есть код:

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="main-block">

    <div>
    </div>
```

Как из `<div class="main-block">` обратится к `<div class="header">` ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под «обратиться» в CSS?

Comment: Нельзя. Css - это каскад: обратиться можно либо к следующему элементу одного уровня, либо к дочернему.

Comment: Дописал вопрос)

Comment: Что или кто вас привел к такому вопросу? Для чего вам это?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato В wordpress хотел дописать стили к элементам сайта не затрагивая "общих" элементов. Просто php не знаю, а в wordpress не очень разбираюсь. Вот) Надеюсь понятно написал)

Comment: Подозреваю что вы хотите [:has](https://doka.guide/css/has/), но он на текущий момент работает только в последней версии Safari.

Но лучше покажите что же вы хотите сделать